# Creating a ListView Adapter giving error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to implement a `ListView` adapter:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

However, when I run my app, I get the following error:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.john.test/com.john.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.john.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;
import com.john.test.API.ApiEndpointInterface;
import com.john.test.models.Post;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements TrendingFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        HotFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        NewFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Post> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<Post>();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //
    }

    class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"Trending", "Hot", "New"};

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new TrendingFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new HotFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new NewFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**PostAdapter.java**

```
package com.john.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.john.test.models.Post;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    public PostAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Post user = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_message);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvName.setText(user.message);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Post.java**

```
package com.john.test.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Post {

    public String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

**post_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
            />

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_trending.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.john.test.TrendingFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColorPrimary="@color/white"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/primary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"
        app:pstsTabTextSize="12dp"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary" />
```

**TrendingFragment.java**

```
package com.john.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.john.test.models.Post;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link TrendingFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link TrendingFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment TrendingFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static TrendingFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TrendingFragment fragment = new TrendingFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public TrendingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);

        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Post> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<Post>();

        Post post1 = new Post("Hey");
        arrayOfUsers.add(post1);

        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfUsers);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

What's causing the error and how can I fix it? I believe it has something to do with my `Fragment` implementation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is `R.id.pager`?

Comment: It's used for this (tabbing library): https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: So, your `ListView` is in your `TrendingFragment`. You should be accessing it in your `TrendingFragment`'s `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put ListView in a layout that is not inflated.

<strike>Change this line</strike>

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_trending);
```

You should move ListView to TrendingFragment and set the ListAdaper inside the fragment.

I don't know how you implement the fragment, but it should look something like this.

**TrendingFragment**

```
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragmnet {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);

        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Post> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<Post>();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference`

Comment: You have to put toolbar in fragment_trending. Post your entire layout and code. Do you want a pager which holds a bunch of ListViews?

Comment: I added the rest of the layouts.

Comment: I still get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference` (after putting toolbar and the others in `fragment_trending.xml`).

Comment: Normally you cant find the view inside fragments from Activity. But this is not the case when it comes to ViewPager. When you use ViewPager, sub fragements will be dynamically created and destroyed. You should access fragements' view in fragment itself as possible.

Comment: I added `TrendingFragment.java` to the original post. I used your edit, but had to change a few things due to errors, but I'm not sure what the return statement should be (since `onCreateView` requires one).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the return statement. Simply return the View we have created :-)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, the point is, the layout you attach to MainActivity via setContentView() doesn't include a ListView.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);
```

this `findViewById` method returns `null`.

Try to access the ListView via fragment.